# Вывод иерархии объектов через запрос Get

Tags: веб-программирование, asp.net, api

Есть такая модель:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Position { get; set; }

    public int WorkExp { get; set; }

    public int Salary { get; set; }

    public int Parent { get; set; }

    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public Employee()
    {
        Employees = new List<Employee>();
    }
}
```

Есть такое свойство `Parent`, которое хранит родителя (то есть кто его босс), и надо вывести через запрос `Get` всю иерархию, чтобы было красиво по лесенке вид.
Я, вроде, понимаю алгоритм, нужна рекурсия, но не могу никак реализовать.
По идее, сначала делаем выборку всех у кого самый маленький `ParentId` (или `=0`(босс)), потом проходим в этой выборке по каждому и так же повторяем действия, но у меня постоянно что-то не то выходит((

Comment: [_но у меня постоянно что-то не то выходит((_](http://memesmix.net/media/created/lcf8v6.jpg)

Comment: еще можно например написать рекурсивное СTE, я к тому, что реализовать выборку проще на стороне сервера.

Comment: Parent - это тот же Employee? Что используете? EF?

Answer (score 0):

Как подсказывают в комментария- проще всего нарисовать процедуру на стороне сервера. Дергаете процедуру и получаете иерархию.

Ваша задача описана на [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).

Есть такая таблица:

```
-- Create an Employee table.
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyEmployees
(
    EmployeeID smallint NOT NULL,
    FirstName nvarchar(30)  NOT NULL,
    LastName  nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
    Title nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    DeptID smallint NOT NULL,
    ManagerID int NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_EmployeeID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EmployeeID ASC) 
);
-- Populate the table with values.
INSERT INTO dbo.MyEmployees VALUES 
 (1, N'Ken', N'Sánchez', N'Chief Executive Officer',16,NULL)
,(273, N'Brian', N'Welcker', N'Vice President of Sales',3,1)
,(274, N'Stephen', N'Jiang', N'North American Sales Manager',3,273)
,(275, N'Michael', N'Blythe', N'Sales Representative',3,274)
,(276, N'Linda', N'Mitchell', N'Sales Representative',3,274)
,(285, N'Syed', N'Abbas', N'Pacific Sales Manager',3,273)
,(286, N'Lynn', N'Tsoflias', N'Sales Representative',3,285)
,(16,  N'David',N'Bradley', N'Marketing Manager', 4, 273)
,(23,  N'Mary', N'Gibson', N'Marketing Specialist', 4, 16);
```

Получаем иерархию:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
WITH DirectReports (ManagerID, EmployeeID, Title, DeptID, Level)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT e.ManagerID, e.EmployeeID, e.Title, edh.DepartmentID, 
        0 AS Level
    FROM dbo.MyEmployees AS e
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory AS edh
        ON e.EmployeeID = edh.BusinessEntityID AND edh.EndDate IS NULL
    WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT e.ManagerID, e.EmployeeID, e.Title, edh.DepartmentID,
        Level + 1
    FROM dbo.MyEmployees AS e
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory AS edh
        ON e.EmployeeID = edh.BusinessEntityID AND edh.EndDate IS NULL
    INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d
        ON e.ManagerID = d.EmployeeID
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT ManagerID, EmployeeID, Title, DeptID, Level
FROM DirectReports
INNER JOIN HumanResources.Department AS dp
    ON DirectReports.DeptID = dp.DepartmentID
WHERE dp.GroupName = N'Sales and Marketing' OR Level = 0;
GO
```

Вроде, все достаточно интуитивно понятно.

У этого решения есть +: Если у вас много людей в БД, то вы почувствуете заметную разницу в производительности.

Если делать это в коде, то вам придется загрузить 100500 людей локально, что займет время и место в памяти, а затем еще обойти все это выстроив иерархию.

Если вы используете другую СУБД, то решение не сильно поменяется.